# ng-model value does not change when select a radio button angularjs 1.7

Tags: angularjs

I have radio buttons bond with a model but when I select a radio-button of them, the model value does not get changed and the ng-change event does not get fired.

```
<div required-field="{{$ctrl.model.requiredField}}" ng-click="$ctrl.model.active = true">
<select required>
    <option selected disabled hidden value="{{$ctrl.model.selected}}">
        {{$ctrl.model.transport.length > 0 ? $ctrl.model.transport : $ctrl.model.generaltext}}
    </option>
</select>
<div class="dropdown-list" ng-if="$ctrl.model.active">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="car in $ctrl.model.cars">
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="car-{{car.id}}" ng-value="car" name="car"
                   ng-model="$ctrl.model.transport"
                   ng-change="$ctrl.model.active = false"
            >
            <label for="car">
                {{car.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I cannot find the reason for such a behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons work for a multiple-choice selection. On/off would be a checkbox.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D